# Spring Roo DBRE - can it generate roo commands

Tags: spring-roo

I have tried Spring Roo's Incremental Database Reverse Engineering (DBRE) where you point it at a database and it determines the schema. Now the information obtained from this is put into an xml file and used to build the Spring skeleton. I am wondering whether anyone has been able to get it to produce Spring Roo commands like what you type in to the roo shell? I'd like to take this and use it in a different project.

I don't really expect this to work more than once - It doesn't need to round-trip.

Cheers

References:
http://www.springsource.org/roo/guide?w=base-dbre

Comment: What do you mean, creating a .roo script file which has 'entity' commands for each entity created by the dbre? Why would that be useful, just use dbre in your other project as well?

Comment: Yes, I mean I want to create a roo script for using the schema elsewhere, but I want to be able to pick and choose what I want - and change things. I can't do that if I am stuck with DBRE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such functionality, I don't think Roo generates `entity` commands internally.
Although you might not be aware of the `--excludeTables` and `--includeTables` parameters described in [this issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1410).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anyone having generated Roo commands from the dbre.xml file, but you could do this by writing and applying a suitable XSLT template. I used to do this with Torque XML schema files, on which the dbre.xml file is based, to generate database scripts and HTML documentation pages.